# Heroku Pipeline Deploy Hook HTTP in app.json

Tags: heroku, heroku-pipelines

I am setting up a Heroku pipeline and I want to add the "add-on" attribute however I did not see them be applied to my environment.

The format of the add ons block is:

`"addons": [
    "sendgrid",
    {
      "plan": "deployhooks:http",
      "as": "SLACK-ENG-STATUS",
      "options": {
        "url": "THIS IS A RANDOM URL"
      }
    }
  ],`

Is that the correct syntax to create the add-on? I do not see the configuration in the staging app when I directly deploy to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you expect your addon to be created on deploy? Because that is not how the app.json works. The app.json only created your addons for:

- Review apps (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#app-json)
- When you use the platform API to create your app (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-up-apps-using-the-heroku-platform-api), including through the Heroku Button

If you already have an existing app, entries in the app.json will not modify it on deploy.

Comment: Thanks. So it sounds like, once either my production or staging app has been created, it will never reference the app.json. So the power really comes from the creation of the Review apps, which will use the app.json file to help create.

Comment: Do you know what the exact environment is assigned to the review applications? 'review' or 'development'?